# ACF MAP - Put a marker to the left side of the map, not center

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, dictionary, advanced-custom-fields

I've got acf google map. I'd like to have map marker (pin) on the left side of the map, because on the right I've got some content and this content covers my pin up. Is is possible to do this in acf?

My code in wordpress (js):

```js
(function($) {

/*
*  new_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type function
*  @date 8/11/2013
*  @since 4.3.0
*
*  @param $el (jQuery element)
*  @return n/a
*/

function new_map( $el ) {

 // var
 var $markers = $el.find('.marker');


 // vars
 var args = {
  zoom  : 14,
  center  : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
  mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  scrollwheel: false,
  styles: [{
          "featureType": "water",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#e9e9e9"
          }, {
            "lightness": 17
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "landscape",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#f5f5f5"
          }, {
            "lightness": 20
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "road.highway",
          "elementType": "geometry.fill",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
          }, {
            "lightness": 17
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "road.highway",
          "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
          }, {
            "lightness": 29
          }, {
            "weight": 0.2
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "road.arterial",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
          }, {
            "lightness": 18
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "road.local",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
          }, {
            "lightness": 16
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "poi",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#f5f5f5"
          }, {
            "lightness": 21
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "poi.park",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#dedede"
          }, {
            "lightness": 21
          }]
        }, {
          "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
          "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "on"
          }, {
            "color": "#ffffff"
          }, {
            "lightness": 16
          }]
        }, {
          "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
          "stylers": [{
            "saturation": 36
          }, {
            "color": "#333333"
          }, {
            "lightness": 40
          }]
        }, {
          "elementType": "labels.icon",
          "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "transit",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#f2f2f2"
          }, {
            "lightness": 19
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "administrative",
          "elementType": "geometry.fill",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#fefefe"
          }, {
            "lightness": 20
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "administrative",
          "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#fefefe"
          }, {
            "lightness": 17
          }, {
            "weight": 1.2
          }]
        }]
 };


 // create map
 var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);
    // popup is shown and map is not visible
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');


 // add a markers reference
 map.markers = [];


 // add markers
 $markers.each(function(){

     add_marker( $(this), map );

 });


 // center map
 center_map( map );


 // return
 return map;

}

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type function
*  @date 8/11/2013
*  @since 4.3.0
*
*  @param $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param map (Google Map object)
*  @return n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

 // var
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );
//console.log($marker.attr('data-lng'));
 var icon = $marker.attr('data-icon');
 // create marker
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position : latlng,
  map   : map,
  icon  : icon
 });

 // add to array
 map.markers.push( marker );

 // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
 if( $marker.html() )
 {
  // create info window
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content  : $marker.html()
  });

  // show info window when marker is clicked
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

   infowindow.open( map, marker );

  });
 }

}

/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type function
*  @date 8/11/2013
*  @since 4.3.0
*
*  @param map (Google Map object)
*  @return n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

 // vars
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

 // loop through all markers and create bounds
 $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

  bounds.extend( latlng );

 });

 // only 1 marker?
 if( map.markers.length == 1 )
 {
  // set center of map
     map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
     map.setZoom( 16 );
 }
 else
 {
  // fit to bounds
  map.fitBounds( bounds );
 }

}

/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type function
*  @date 8/11/2013
*  @since 5.0.0
*
*  @param n/a
*  @return n/a
*/
// global var
var map = null;

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.acf-map').each(function(){

  // create map
  map = new_map( $(this) );

 });

});

})(jQuery);
```

My working code in html:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

    function init() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.060565, 19.920922 + 0.026),
        styles: [{
          "featureType": "water",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#e9e9e9"
          }, {
            "lightness": 17
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "landscape",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#f5f5f5"
          }, {
            "lightness": 20
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "road.highway",
          "elementType": "geometry.fill",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
          }, {
            "lightness": 17
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "road.highway",
          "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
          }, {
            "lightness": 29
          }, {
            "weight": 0.2
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "road.arterial",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
          }, {
            "lightness": 18
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "road.local",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
          }, {
            "lightness": 16
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "poi",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#f5f5f5"
          }, {
            "lightness": 21
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "poi.park",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#dedede"
          }, {
            "lightness": 21
          }]
        }, {
          "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
          "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "on"
          }, {
            "color": "#ffffff"
          }, {
            "lightness": 16
          }]
        }, {
          "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
          "stylers": [{
            "saturation": 36
          }, {
            "color": "#333333"
          }, {
            "lightness": 40
          }]
        }, {
          "elementType": "labels.icon",
          "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "transit",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#f2f2f2"
          }, {
            "lightness": 19
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "administrative",
          "elementType": "geometry.fill",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#fefefe"
          }, {
            "lightness": 20
          }]
        }, {
          "featureType": "administrative",
          "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#fefefe"
          }, {
            "lightness": 17
          }, {
            "weight": 1.2
          }]
        }]
      };
      var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.060565, 19.920922),
        map: map,
        title: 'Dom ubezpieczeń'
      });
    }
```

I suppose, that there is sth connected with +/- 0.026 or another value. Where to put it? Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution is to modify center_map() function:

```js
function center_map( map ) {

 // vars
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

 // loop through all markers and create bounds
 $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

  bounds.extend( latlng );

 });

 // only 1 marker?
 if( map.markers.length == 1 )
 {
        
        // get the current center
        theCenter = bounds.getCenter();
        
        // set center of map
     map.setCenter( {lat: theCenter.lat(), lng: theCenter.lng() + 0.026} );
     map.setZoom( 16 );
 }
 else
 {
  // fit to bounds
  map.fitBounds( bounds );
 }

}
```